# API data not populated in tableview inswift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am getting Api data into Array format and bring to populate on table view . I also have check by taking sample data in array its working but in Api data don't

**CODE**

```
      var json: NSArray!
        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? NSArray
            print(json)
            print(json.valueForKey("name"))
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        self.TableData = json.valueForKey("name") as! Array<String>
        print(self.TableData[0])
         print(self.TableData)
       print(self.TableData.count)

    }
    task.resume()
```

Here the value is coming and also the the number of values.

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    //return data.count
    return TableData.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
  //  cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.backgroundColor? = UIColor.blueColor()
    return cell
}
```

In this section the tableData.count is not taking the number of values to show the number of cell. I have tried by taking sample data its working.

```
      var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()

     var data = ["hello","how","are","u"]
```

Any one tell me the solution . where is the error??

Comment: I think you don't have reload tableview after you get your array.

Comment: Can you show your json response?

Comment: o thanks @Bhumika  It worked. Reload was missing